# Page size: Firefox add on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Does anyone know any Firefox add-on that can show you the size of the current viewing page?

Comment: The answer is out of date, no longer applies to latest Firefox.

Answer (score 12):

If you're optimizing your page size (in kilobytes, not pixels!) you need to know both the compressed sizes of each element if your server is gzipping your output.  You can't get that with the standard web browser "right-click-->Properties."

The Web Developer Toolbar extension, mentioned in another reply, does this.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60

I haven't found another tool that reports the compressed and uncompressed sizes for each page element so conveniently.

Install Web Developer Toolbar and go to Tools-->Web Developer-->Page Information-->View Document Size.  Very handy!

```
Scripts (7 files)   82 KB (243 KB uncompressed)

- http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Js/jquery.package.master.js?d=20081101   39 KB (109 KB uncompressed)
- http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Js/wmd-base.js   15 KB (59 KB uncompressed)
- http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js 9 KB (22 KB uncompressed)
- http://stackoverflow.com/content/js/jquery.package.question.js?cachebreaker=20090107  8 KB (27 KB uncompressed)
- http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Js/showdown.js   4 KB (10 KB uncompressed)
- http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Js/jquery.package.editor.js?cachebreaker=20081008.1  3 KB (9 KB uncompressed)
- http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Js/wmd-plus.js   3 KB (7 KB uncompressed)

Style Sheets (3 files)  7 KB (27 KB uncompressed)

- http://stackoverflow.com/Content/all.css?d=20081101   6 KB (26 KB uncompressed)
- http://stackoverflow.com/Content/print.css    705 bytes (1 KB uncompressed)
```

If there is a better tool for this, I'd love to hear about it.  This feature is about the only thing that keeps me from ditching Web Developer Toolbar entirely for Firebug.  Maybe YSlow does this; need to research more.

Comment: "View Document Size" seems to not exist in the current (2.0.5) version of Web Developer.

Answer (score 6):

[Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) (dimensions) or [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) (for page size and loading times) for Firebug.

Answer (score 5):

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) if you want an in-depth analysis. Right-click and "View Page Info" if you just want the final number.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in `Inspect Element (Q)` from the right-click menu can do this. Go to the `Network` tab, reload and have a look:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

FireBug allows you to see the page size and the size of all aditional downloads (css files, images and such). 
It also allows you to do all kinds cool debugging things.

Answer (score 2):

The FireFox View page is the size of the HTML.   The WebDeveloper add on breaks down the other requests embedded in the page such as CSS, Images, javascripts... etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Add-on :
lori : Life-of-request info :-
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1743

It display how long it took to fully retrieve the page, it's total size(including items from browser cache), and how many requests done to get the page .